# Error in .Net Web Service running on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6

I am trying to run a web service build in .Net on IIS 6 server.
But it is giving an Error while starting Web Service

> **ERROR**
>
> **Server Error in ' /9448' Application**
>
> ***Configuration Error***
>
> **Description** :  "An error occurred during the processing of configuration file required to service this request.Please review the
>   specific details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> **Parse Error Message** :An error occurred loading the configuration file: Access to the path
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config"
>   is denied.
>
> **Source Error**:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> **Source File** : C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config
>   **Line: 0**
>
> **Version Information** : Microsoft.NET Framework Version v2.0.50727.3625; ASP.Net Version : v2.0.50727.3625

The user under which it is running have full Administrator Rights

While it was working fine previously

What could be the problem?

Comment: Two suggestions, due to things I have seen at clients. 1. does administrator have write access to that folder? 2. Is there a deny access setting for that folder for any group the app pool user belongs to? Deny overrides Allow.

Comment: I would fire up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see which user actually is trying to access the "machine.config" file.